# Jquery page transition not smooth

Tags: jquery

i started learning jquery and put a couple of page fadeIn and fadeout methods. It works fine on my localhost. when i put it on a server, the transition effects are not smooth. the body content fadesout and footer part is coming up before transfering to next page and also my  header stutters after going to next page.

i am using following code in every page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#matter1').hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $('a.nav_font').click(function(){
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#matter1').fadeOut(1000, function(){
          window.location.href = link;
      });
      return false;
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(function() { ... })` makes a function run when the DOM is ready. Unfortunately for you, browsers render content as it loads, so the overall effect is that the browser renders the document as it loads, and then after it's loaded you hide it and fade it in.

This wasn't visible on your local machine because the content loads so quickly that the browser might not get a chance to incrementally render it before your code runs. On a real server where there's a delay, the browser has a chance to render before the DOM is ready.

Rather than using the on-DOM-ready callback as the trigger to hide it, try hiding it as the absolute first thing inside `#matter1`:

```
<div id="matter1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#matter1").hide();
    </script>
    ...
```

Then as soon as `#matter1` exists it will be hidden. Then in your DOM-ready handler, do everything as before, except that the `.hide()` is now unnecessary.

Comment: @abc123: And make your site completely useless to users without JavaScript enabled? No thanks.